# What does しっかりしてください in this context mean?

Tags: meaning, japanese-to-english

I've came across this one page comic panel about an apprentice girl and her teacher, the teacher then give her a job which he said will be "handy" (手頃な) for the apprentice but the truth it is actually not.

After she done with her job, the apprentice said this:

> **あなたの「手頃」は本当に信用なりません。しっかりしてください。**

So what does *しっかりしてください* mean in this?
I have known that it has some meaning like *"Pull yourself together/Get it together"* but I do not think it will suit with the above context.

Answer (score 2):

As you can see in [this entry](https://jisho.org/word/%E7%A2%BA%E3%82%8A), しっかり has various meanings. It is not only an antonym for *confused* or *drowsy*, but also an antonym for *unserious*, *messy*, *loose*, and so on. しっかりして in a context like this means "get serious and do your job right". She is asking her teacher to think again and give her a task of appropriate difficulty.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure of the exact context, but I suppose 手頃な should mean more precisely 'easy enough' in the conversation. And the apprentice says the phrase because it wasn't easy at all. しっかりしてください means 'pull yourself together' with respect to the assessing the difficulty of the job on the teacher's side, so more literally means something like 'think more about how *really* difficult/easy a job is' (= pull yourself about thinking).